# Delphi VirtualStringTree OnGetHint

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I want to show hint when cell text is already fully shown.
so, on form's OnCreate

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VirtualStringTree1.HintMode := hmHint;
  VirtualStringTree1.ShowHint := True;
end;
```

and OnGetHint

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1GetHint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var LineBreakStyle: TVTTooltipLineBreakStyle; var HintText: string);
begin
  HintText := IntToStr(Node.Index);
end;
```

but nothing happens.

OnGetHint event handler is not fired and even TBaseVirtualTree.CMHintShow breakpoint is not working.

what can I supposed to do?

I`m using delphi xe3, virtualtreeview 5.2.1.

---

Thanks for the answer.

I followed your guide.

Application properties

- `ShowHint := True` // I checked but set to true on OnCreate explicitly

Vst propertiess

- `Hint`, e.g. 'Hint for the whole VST' // yes, add meaningless hint
- `HintAnimation`, e.g. `hatNone`
- `HintMode`, e.g. `hmHintAndDefault` // as you see, on OnCreate
- `ShowHint`, `True`// as you see, on OnCreate
- `ParentShowHint`, as needed, use `False` if you don't know // yes

Vst events to implement

- `OnDrawHint()` // yes
- `OnGetHint()` // yes
- `OnGetHintSize()` // yes

but nothing changed.
OnGetHint, OnGetHintSize, OnDrawHint are not fired at all.
(when HintMode set to hmToolTip and text is not fully shown, OnGetHint is fired only)

And yes, I read that documentation `VirtualTreeView.pdf`.
but all description about Event is exactly same as your quote.
I need more explanation.

---

**Update:**

Very weird thing.
I have tested this other PCs.

My PC
`Windows 10`
`xe3`
`vst 5.2.1`

- not work

PC 1
`Windows 10`
`xe3`
`vst 5.2.1`

- compile and execute // work
- compile on My PC, copy and execute // work

PC 2
`Windows 10`

- compile on My PC, copy and execute // work

What????
the code was not the problem.
I don't know why and even where to start.

anyway, I really thanks about answer and accept it.
if anyone knows about this weird thing, please let me know.
if I find out, I will update.

Comment: You don't have Application.ShowHint set to FALSE anywhere, do you?

Comment: @Dsm Application.ShowHint is TRUE, I checked. additionally, when HintMode := hmToolTip and text is not fully shown, it works properly and trigger OnGetHint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several properties and event handlers must be in place/implemented for node specific hints to show. The following should get you started:

Application properties

- `ShowHint := True`

Vst properties

- `Hint`, e.g. 'Hint for the whole VST'
- `HintAnimation`, e.g. `hatNone`
- `HintMode`, e.g. `hmHintAndDefault`
- `ShowHint`, `True`
- `ParentShowHint`, as needed, use `False` if you don't know

Vst events to implement

- `OnDrawHint()`
- `OnGetHint()`
- `OnGetHintSize()`

From the documentation:

> Use an event handler for `OnDrawHint()` to draw the hint or tooltip
>   for the given node. You must implement this event and
>   `OnGetHintSize()` to get a hint at all.

Look on the net for `VirtualTreeView.pdf` for documentation